# RSA decryption of a column in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, cryptography

I tried to use the `crpytography` module to peform RSA decryption on a column in my Spark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa import _RSAPrivateKey


def decrypt(encoded_ciphertext: str, key: _RSAPrivateKey) -> str:
    if encoded_ciphertext is None:
        return ""
    try:
        decoded_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(encoded_ciphertext)
        decrypted_data = key.decrypt(decoded_ciphertext, padding.PKCS1v15())
        return decrypted_data.decode("utf-8")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Decryption error: {e}")
        return ""


decrypt_udf = udf(decrypt_data, StringType())
sdf.withColumn(
    "decrypted",
    decrypt_udf(sdf["encrypted"]),
).show()
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_cffi_backend.FFI' object

**Unfortunately**, `crpytography` uses a `_cffi_backend.FFI` object somewhere and the is one its dependencies:

```
pipdeptree --packages cryptography
cryptography==3.4.8
└── cffi [required: >=1.12, installed: 1.16.0]
    └── pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.21]
```

Apparently, PySpark cannot pickle C objects such as _cffi_backend.FFI.

I could convert my Spark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe and then it would work, but the function is really, **really** slow. Not to mention that the dataframe is massive and I have to call `limit()` on it to fit it into memory.